# web scraping authentication node js

Tags: node.js, authentication, web-scraping

this is my code ,this is not authenticated, and does the desired scraping, anyone know where this error,If anyone knows of another way and may give an example is the appreciate.This code is to scraping to a website that requires authentication, I do not see how the link will appear to give me

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';//

var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');


req = request.defaults({
jar: true,                 // Guardar las cookies hacia un jar

});
var credentials = {
username: 'user',
password: 'pass'
};

req.post({
    uri: 'http://www.website.com/',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials)
}, function(err, res, body){
if(err) {
console.log(err);
return;
}

req('http://www.website.com/info', function(err, res,       data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    console.log($.html());
        
    
    
});

});
```

It just is not authenticated and therefore does scrapping desired

Comment: There is nothing duplicated, you have to read well, are different topics

Comment: which is called?, can you explain a little better your idea, which is the order of the code to work .thanks

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code.  Please format your code before posting it - your indentation is very misleading.

Comment: ok take your advice, but then?, sees something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

How does the remote site hold the authentication? Did you remember to save the cookie from the authentication call, then pass in the cookie in subsequent URLs which requires authentication?

Comment: Thank you for responding Bill, if the site is asp.net authentication and has in that line request.defaults req = ({
jar: true,

});
keep cookies, is the right way?

Comment: In the docs for the request module it states `jar - If true and tough-cookie is installed, remember cookies for future use (or define your custom cookie jar; see examples section)` (see https://github.com/request/request)

Comment: Thanks Bill, tell me you tested this code and you turned out?